# How can I display photos when I click dropdown items with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

I'm new to the world of React. I'm doing a simple react project with Ant Design. I have a dropdown menu in my project and I have items of this menu. I want to display photos on the screen dynamically when I click on the items.For example, When I click option 1, I want a photo to appear on the screen. When I click option 2, I want a different photo to appear on the screen etc... Alert pops up when i click on it now. But how can i display the photo. Please give me opinion. How can I do?

This is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Menu, Dropdown, Button, message } from "antd";
import "./SingleDropdown.css"

function SingleDropdown() {

function handleMenuClick(e) {
message.info("Image showed");
console.log("click", e);
}

const menu = (
 <Menu onClick={handleMenuClick}>
   <Menu.Item key="1">
    Option 1
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="2">
    Option 2
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="3">
    Option 3
  </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
);

return (
<div className="singledropdown">
<Dropdown overlay={menu}>
  <Button className="button-color">
    Dropdown
  </Button>
</Dropdown>
</div>
);
}

export default SingleDropdown;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `antd` is able to do that.
Refer the link [here](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/#components-dropdown-demo-dropdown-button)

Futuremore, you may try to take a look at the API below, I think that helps :D

On the other hand, you may try `onClick` function in React, since I worked with [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/) it worked, and I think `antd` is able to handle that too.

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
const menu = (
 <Menu onClick={handleMenuClick}>
   <Menu.Item key="1" onClick={this.showPic1}>
    Option 1
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="2" onClick={this.showPic2}>
    Option 2
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="3" onClick={this.showPic3}>
    Option 3
  </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
);
```

*Show you some example how it works

`onClick` is a React function, this is the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) You may brief around and see how that works :D

Comment: I'll check out. Thanks for your helps.